# PTVS plugin for applications that embed python

Tags: c++, python, ptvs

For an application that "embeds" python, can the PTVS plugin be used for mixed-mode debugging ? To be more specific, let's assume that there is an executable (written in C/C++) called "my_executable" that can be run from the command line, with an option to execute a python script file:

```
./my_executable -exec_script some_script_file.py
```

In this case, is it possible to use the PTVS plugin to achieve mixed-mode debugging ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is supported if you attach to the process via Debug -> Attach to Process, and enable both Python and Native engines at the same time.

Comment: Any documentation for PTVS should say this in big bold letters right at the top with the <blink> tag.   Is there someway to add a button to run the debug process and then automatically attach to it?

Comment: Unfortunately not.